# Not able to create database under analysis services

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence

I am trying to create a database under Analysis services but while creating the database.

I am getting below error message:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Errors in the metadata manager. The '\\?\E:\SQL Server 2016\MSAS13.SQL2016\OLAP\Data\VBAMDX.0.asm' storage location of the 'dfjdlskjfds' database can not be located under the server data directory.
 (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.Core)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are currently no databases then stop the SQL Server Analysis Services service from “Start... Run... services.msc”. Then make a copy of the current contents of the Data folder (just in case) then delete all folders and files in the Data folder. Now restart the SSAS service and it will create the necessary files and folders for a working but empty SSAS instance.

Comment: I think we cannot directly create a database under analysis server. When I deployed my first cube, it automatically created the database under analysis server.  but thanks a lot for get back on my question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and that Neeraj has already resolved it, but Google brought me here in 2022.

So this error is poorly worded:

> storage location of the 'dfjdlskjfds' database can not be located
> under the server data directory.

It implies that the storage location cannot be found, when what it really means is "You can't create a new database in the server data directory."

To resolve it, specify a Storage Location that is not within the server data directory, by either manually typing a folder path, or by adding additional folder paths to the list of AllowedBrowsingFolders in the config - https://bzzzt.io/post/2014-03/2014-03-18-ssas-server-properties-allowedbrowsingfolders/